# MySql complex query to count each person orders

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with orders in which in Comments record there is a name of the order creator.
There is 3 sales people. I want to fetch statistics from each sales person.
I came up with below query to output one person's orders and it works fine but I really struggle if it possible in one select query to fetch orders of each sales person and output in the same table. I tried Union and select within select but I guess I am constructing the query wrong. The below works fine to output just Adam's orders(Qty sold and total Sales value for that person).Thanks for any tips.

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(orders.despatched) as Month, YEAR(orders.despatched) as Year, 
SUM(orders.price) as AdamSales, COUNT(orders.comment) as AdamQt FROM orders 
WHERE 
orders.comment LIKE '%Adam%' AND 
orders.status = 'despatched' AND 
orders.despatched BETWEEN '$d1' AND '$d2' 
GROUP BY YEAR(orders.despatched), MONTH(orders.despatched)
order by orders.despatched ";
```

I know that possibly grouping by Person would be best if only the person's name wasn't just a string somewhere inside Comment record.

Answer (score 1):

you can do group by on the case statement based on the comments

```
SELECT 
       ( case when ORDERs.comments LIKE '%Adam%' THEN 'Adam'  
                 when ORDERS.comments LIKE '%Peter%' THEN 'Peter' END ) as 'Person'
       MONTHNAME(orders.despatched) as Month, 
       YEAR(orders.despatched) as Year, 
       SUM(orders.price) as Sales, 
       COUNT(orders.comment) as Qt FROM orders 
WHERE 
(orders.comment LIKE '%Adam%' OR orders.comment LIKE '%Peter%' ) AND
orders.status = 'despatched' AND 
orders.despatched BETWEEN '$d1' AND '$d2' 
GROUP BY YEAR(orders.despatched), MONTH(orders.despatched),
     ( case when ORDERs.comments LIKE '%Adam%' THEN 'Adam'  
                 when ORDERS.comments LIKE '%Peter%' THEN 'Peter' END )
order by orders.despatched
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. So what is actually first case in brackets doing? Saving the result name value to Person? I have to have all the values for each person separate, outputing in each loop quantities of each sales person orders for example  October: Adam 136 | Peter: 213; November: Adam 156 | Peter: 203

Comment: @Milosz, it will print out put like Person, Month, year, Sales, orders as headers and Adam  October, 2014, 2,4  like that

Comment: Keep getting:  mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource. I am saving the query to $sql and then: $result = mysql_query($sql, $con); and then loop: while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $record['Month'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $record['Year'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $record['Person'] . '</td>';

Comment: @Milosz, when the SQL is run directly on MYSQL , does it give any error.

Comment: Thanks after clearing some tiny errors I got it working but I wanted to output the persons names as top column headers so there is no redundancy. In the above example I will have repeated September row for each different name. I want to save individually result for each name to be able to have result row as follows for each month: September | 2014 | AdamQty | AdamSales | PeterQty | PeterSales (where AdamQt is count of his orders etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If the person's name is just a string, then what you need is to Group By on a Case expression that will return 1 for the first person, 2 for the second, etc.; something like:

```
Group by Case When orders.comment LIKE '%Adam%' then 1 When ... End, ...
```

Or course, the real solution would be to add a table for Persons and add a relationship to it.